# ui:MenuItem change label dynamically

Tags: label

In my component file I have a button menu and one of the menu items is defined as below:

```
<lightning:menuItem label="Edit Properties " value="Edit" />
```

And I have a select event handler on the button menu.

```
handleSelectMenuItem : function(cmp, event, helper) {

    var selectedMenuItemValue = event.getParam("value");

    switch(selectedMenuItemValue){  
        case "Edit":
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to change the label from "Edit Properties" to a different value for this menu item when this menu item is selected.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Aura` binding.

Define a label attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="menuItemLabel" type="String" default="Edit" />
```

And in your `menuItem`, make the label reference that attribute:

```
<lightning:menuItem label="{!v.menuItemLabel}" value="Edit" />
```

In your select handler, you can change the attribute to a different value:

```
switch(selectedMenuItemValue){  
    case "Edit":
    component.set("v.menuItemLabel","Save");
    break;
}
```